# Execution took 60006 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

If you run a simple example like this locally:

```
export async function runTimeout(req, res) {
    // console.log('Request:\n\n', req);
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await timeout(80000);
        resolve();
    });
    res.status(200).send('Timeout complete');
}

function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Using the commands:

> firebase serve --only functions

You will see that this times out at 60 seconds every time, according to the firebase github issues list the default for **localhost** should now stand at 9 minutes (which is the max) so their is no need to configure it. Does anyone know why I am timing out at 60 seconds vs being able to complete the full 80 seconds (as in this example) or more?

The error message is:

> info: Execution took 62033 ms, finished with status: 'timeout' info:
>   Execution took 62043 ms, finished with status: 'crash' error:
>   Something went wrong with the function! error:  Error: Can't set
>   headers after they are sent.
>       at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
>       at ServerResponse.header (/Users/hackintosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/Users/hackintosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (/Users/hackintosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
>       at ProxyServer.Supervisor._proxy.on (/Users/hackintosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/supervisor/supervisor.js:107:14)
>       at ProxyServer.emit (/Users/hackintosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/eventemitter3/index.js:144:27)
>       at ClientRequest.proxyError (/Users/hackintosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/passes/web-incoming.js:156:18)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)

Answer (score 7):

The [default timeout](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) for all deployed functions is 60 seconds.  When the function timeout duration elapses, Cloud Functions will clamp down resources on your function, causing it terminate, and leave that error in your log.

You can configure the timeout of your function deployed by the Firebase CLI in the Cloud console (not in the Firebase console, and not by the CLI, currently).  The [maximum timeout](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits) is 540 seconds (9 minutes).

Also, there are perhaps one significant error in your function that may make it behave differently than you expect.  You are returning a promise from runTimeout that prevents the following line (res.send) from ever executing, under any circumstance.  If you don't send a response to the client, your function will also timeout, as the sent response marks the end of your function's execution.

Comment: I appreciate that tip, but actually this is specifically when testing on the localhost environment only. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect the local emulator to behave differently than the server?

Comment: Also, I edited the answer to point out a possible error in your code.

Comment: Hi Doug, I don't expect the local emulator to behave differently, I am just wondering how do I configure the local emulator to have the 540 second time out? I've configured the live environment already, but it would be great to also be able to test the extended timeout locally as well.

Comment: In that case, you should file a feature request.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/  And also cite this issue that suggests the core emulator has this capability, but needs to be propagated to the Firebase CLI.  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/66

Comment: I've added a bug to the cloud emulator (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/218) curiously they say it should work already (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/66) but I was unable to get these flags to have the intended effect.

Comment: If you were trying to pass values from the Firebase CLI to the cloud emulator, that won't work.  The CLI needs to be modified to pass values through.  The emulator parameters only work with the gcloud command line.

Comment: You can also change the timeout time in the normal edit menu of a Google Cloud Function.